# How do I redirect 404's to index.html and rewrite the URL to the home page URL?

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I changed a bulky, complex website into a small one-page website, so users need to be redirected from 404s to index.html.

I put this in **.htaccess**:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

If you type **mydomain.com/lalalalala**, this redirects to the home page content (**mydomain.com/index.html**), but the URL bar still says **mydomain.com/lalalalala**.

How do I redirect 404s to **index.html** and rewrite the URL to **mydomain.com**?

EDIT:

I'm using Bluehost.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use these 2 lines at the top of your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/
```

`DirectoryIndex` will make `http://domain.com/` load `http://domain.com/index.html` by default and use of `http://` in `ErrorDocument` will make it redirect to new URL.

Comment: or just: ErrorDocument 404 /

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404 /` will not change URL in browser

Comment: for me adding ErrorDocument was enough.

Comment: Any insight in whether this is a good practice? Is it not more appropriate (and perhaps SEO abiding?) to have beautiful error pages with navigation to possible important entry points of the website?

Comment: @s3c: This question was not about SEO. There can be some internal websites that are not open to public.

Answer (score 4):

Try below code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

It's any `404 url` to your `home page.`

Comment: Using the rewrite lines created a redirect loop for me. Just using ErrorDocument 404 /index.php by itself appears to work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html  
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/
```

this would work for broken links. apply in `.htaccess` file and then check any broken link tool.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the accepted answer. What value does it add?