# Redirect to HTML page using web.config file

Tags: html, visual-studio

I've been working on a ASP.NET web application project in Visual Studio. In that project, when the user enters the hostname they get a 404 error but what I would like to happen is for them to be redirected to the index.html when they have just entered the hostname.

I was wondering how this is done. Below is the code that I used but it didn't work

```
<location path="">
   <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="../index.html" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
   </system.webServer>
 </location>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: what you need to do share you code

Comment: Use `.htaccess` file that redirects all `404` errors

Comment: I think this can be done via .htaccess. How's your server?

Comment: What's the name of your html file?  Your server has a default document specified, which it returns if no specific file is requested.  I'm guessing that the default document is index.html or index.htm.  If you are on IIS, it's default.html/default.htm.  Rename your html file to either of those names and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess file to redirect 404 to another page. Check the answer in this post:
[How do I redirect 404's to index.html and rewrite the URL to the home page URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493540/how-do-i-redirect-404s-to-index-html-and-rewrite-the-url-to-the-home-page-url)

Comment: Thanks, I'm relatively new to this so having a little bit of difficulty. I don't know where I would find the .htaccess file

Comment: `.htaccess` should live in the root folder of your public www directory...if there's not one, I believe you can just create one...note that the `.` ensures that the file is hidden, so you may have the file but just make sure hidden files are showing, or use the `ls -a` command in terminal to show hidden files...

Comment: .htaccess file is a configuration file of Apache. You can find how and when to use .htaccess file here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Why do you guys assume he's running Apache?

Comment: **she's. After some research I think I need to put the redirect into the web.config file... it's an ASP.NET web application

Comment: No you dont.  Whats yhe name of the html file you want to be shown by default?

Comment: It's index.html